# Issue with a XHR in Google Chrome extension on Secure connection (https) , xhr.status = 0

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I have given the permission in manifest file, though when I try to make XHR to https://wh2.sibers.com I am just getting a xhr.readystate = 4, xhr.status = 0; 
I can do XHR request just fine from the console(under the wh2.sibers.com page of course). Anybody has a broader knowledge in this things please show me the direction, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving full `https://*/*` permission (if you have only site specific). I faced similar problem recently, looks like a bug with https redirects.

Comment: hi please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325437/chrome-extension-xhr-request-getting-cancelled. i do have the same problem not getting resolved