# Chrome extension xhr request getting cancelled

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, permissions, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to build a chrome extension which uses a xhr request to get response from a external api. I have set the permission for the extension as mention in the chrome extension document still xhr request is getting cancelled in network.

manifest.json

```
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_title": "Chrome extension title"
  },
 "permissions": [
     "activeTab",
     "storage",
     "https://*/"
 ]
```

In popup.js

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://putsreq.com/4z01VNOBPeD144njWNdi", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var theValue = "asdfassf";
    alert("This is doen");
    // chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': theValue}, ()=> {
    //   // Notify that we saved.
    // document.location.href = "timer.html";
    // });
 }
}
xhr.send();
```

Comment: 1. Reload the extensions on chrome://extensions page 2. rightclick the popup, `Inspect`, check the console for errors.

Comment: Yes I did reload many times. And in network tab in console the request  shows cancelled

Comment: Something else is interfering. The posted code is correct.

Comment: @wOxxOm do u have working app of calling external script?

Answer (score 3):

I missed to add event.preventDefault(), that used to cancel the default form submit.  When i added event.preventDefault() code to the above code it worked.

Comment: Where did you add the preventDefault() and how did that fix it?

Comment: you have to add it inside button click

Comment: This makes sense. Should be in the chrome extension documentation if not. Put in the click handler. For example in jQuery: `$('#loginButton').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I've been struggling with this for the last couple of days. Adding the preventDefault fixed the issue I was having.